# When you access (Meta) Stack Overflow from Indonesia, Singapore or Sri Lanka you might be greeted with a Varnish error

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, fastly

The following error occur on and off when you're located in Indonesia, Singapore  or Sri Lanka:

> [image]

This happens both on Stack Overflow as Meta, as well as on other sites across the network. One of the ISP involved is *starhub fibre*.

So far users encountered 4 states:

- HTTP 503
- I/O error (head)
- Handshake error
- Content loaded, but no CSS

Error details:

- Details: `cache-hkg17929-HKG 1513588999 1771987871`
- Details: `cache-sin18033-SIN 1513588170 1715501570`

Can this be looked at and/or can Fastly be contacted to restore their services?

[*reported in chat by two users, I post on their behalf*](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6566286#6566286)

Comment: Am in SEA. Cannot reproduce any of these errors. I've had no issues with the site all day.

Comment: @BoltClock I've pinned down the locations a bit more. Are you still in that same area?

Comment: Yeah, just noticed Journeyman is one of the users you mention, I live in the same country and I'm not experiencing any issues.

Comment: Seems sporadic - that's my error, and I'm on now, another user in india 
 - Pandya mentioned the same error.

Comment: Are you on a special ISP/VPN/company network @BoltClock?

Comment: No, I'm just on one of the major ISPs, though IIRC not the same one.

Comment: I'm on starhub fibre (in singapore) - seems back up now, but worth posting for SO Inc to follow up if need be. Saw a similar error on SU as well

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: Well... I got nothing.

Comment: Close-voters: Just because _you_ can't reproduce the issue, doesn't mean the issue isn't real. There have been ___multiple___ cases of this issue already.

Comment: I was able to reproduce at the time after I configured my VPN to route my traffic through Singapore.

Comment: @cerbrus they didnt realize that part of the steps to reproduce was to pack up their families and move to singapore, establish housing, then get an internet contract with the specified ISP. Lazy close voters,  sheesh

Comment: @TinyGiant turns out getting the Internet contract was the hardest part ...

Comment: This happened to me in Bangkok today too. But only for about an hour.

Comment: Just checking in to say that I've still had zero issues on my end (and it wasn't clear before but I'm under the same ISP as @Journeyman Geek, looks like I misremembered).

Comment: Yesterday I noticed this issue in Pakistan as well. However in my case this error appears on SO site (not on meta)

Comment: Yesterday I noticed this issue in Bangalore, India as well. However in my case this error appears on SO site (not on meta) @MohammadUsman Thanks for the message ;)

Comment: Haven't faced it from Sri Lanka. (For me)

Comment: I experienced this yesterday in Malaysia as well and I thought it was something to do with my ISP. Although, it did come back in 2 mins.

Comment: am from India, I got this issue briefly yesterday, but another website altogether.. though SO was also open in another tab and working...

Comment: I'm from Sri Lanka and never did I encounter such errors and I was online on stackoverflow whole day

Comment: I'm from Singapore, I had this for about 20 minutes yesterday (to all StackExchange sites, not just StackOverflow)

Comment: As this is coming from a Varnish cache server, I would say it's probably nothing to do with Stack Overflow. It's more likely a transparent proxy server used by the ISP.

Comment: @DavidG please note green lock icon on browser omnibox which states that connection is not interrupted by ISP.

Comment: @galeksandrp Well, if you've got the ISP's root cert' on your machine and no HSTS (which iirc SE doesn't use) it could well be interrupted.

Comment: @galeksandrp And I'm fairly sure SO don't have Varnish in their setup, so it must be external.

Comment: @DavidG it is not their server indeed but I expect it to be of Fastly which is their CDN/cache/off-load provider. I'm not familiar with Fastly but IIRC SE does configure stuff on their services.

Comment: Can confirm in Singapore. I saw this issue a bunch of times 2 days back. Have not see in the last 2 days though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastly reported some routing issues in their Singapore infrastructure [on the 18th](https://status.fastly.com/incidents/bk90gs9cn2x7) - unless anyone has had more issues since then, I suspect that these issues were caused by that outage.  Let us know!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the headers, it does look like fastly*

According to the Fastly FAQ:

https://docs.fastly.com/guides/debugging/common-503-errors#error-503-backendmax_conn-reached

> This error occurs when Varnish makes a request to a backend in your Fastly service that has reached its defined maximum number of connections. By default, Fastly limits you to 200 origin connections from a single edge node to protect the origins from overload. For the majority of sites, this should be enough. If you get this error message with less than 10,000 non-hit requests per second, make sure your origin is responding normally (e.g., there are no origin slow downs). If you just increase the number of maximum connections, you may be exacerbating the problem. If you have determined that your origin is not the issue, increase the maximum connections limit to your origin or reach out to Fastly support for further help with this issue. This error may also appear as "Error 503 maximum threads for service reached."

So it's possible it's a stack exchange origin problem instead or maybe SO is so lovely and popular that the limits need increasing :-).

I don't see an Indian, Sri Lankan nor Indonesian POP, but there is Singapore and Hong Kong. https://www.fastly.com/network-map/

I've added a fastly tag to grab it some attention.

*At least from my perspective in the UK, I don't have an Asian proxy handy to double check the headers.

Comment: p.s. the Fastly guys are pretty awesome, so if it's a Stackoverflow or Fastly configuration tweak I'm sure it'll be sorted in no time :-)